# Git show-branch command returns different output in Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins

the "git show-branch" command returns from local clone the commit history of the current branch, including its parent branch:

```
[me@server project]$ git show-branch
! [branch1] Commit 1
 * [branch2] Commit 2
  ! [main] Minor fix
---
 *  [branch2] Commit 2
+*  [branch1] Commit 1
+*+ [main] Minor fix
```

I have a Jenkins job, which checks out the code similar to this:

```
checkout ([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: '*/*']],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: [],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        credentialsId: 'id123',
        url: 'https://url123.com/repo.git'
    ]]
])
```

Now, if I'm checking out a specific branch and issueing the "git show-branch" command from Jenkins, the result contains only the commit of the current branch, and nothing from the parent.

```
[Pipeline] bat

C:\jenkins\workspace\project>git show-branch
[branch2] Commit 2
[Pipeline]
```

As you see I am not using shallow checkout, but the history is still missing. The git versions are the same. I haven't found any setting regarding showbranch.default, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch which could have affection.

Would you please advise? Many thanks.

Comment: Are you running the checkout step in an manually created Pipeline Job or do you use a Multi-Branch Job or an Organization Folder?

Comment: The checkout step is done in a manually created job.

Answer (score 1):

AFAK Jenkins does not create local branches (`refs/heads/`) for all remote ones (`refs/remotes/.../`); but `show-branch` only shows local ones.

As the linked documentation says (emphasis mine):

> ```
> git show-branch [...]
>       [(<rev> | <glob>)…​]
> ```
>
> Shows the commit ancestry graph starting from the commits named with
> `<rev>`s or `<glob>`s (*or all refs under `refs/heads` and/or `refs/tags`*)
> semi-visually.

Maybe on Jenkins `git show-branch refs/remotes/origin/*` does what you want?

But be careful, after initial checkout Jenkins will only update the ref for the branch being currently built!

---

Edit:

The `branches: [[name: "*/*"]]` most likely does not do what you want, it will only determine a single branch from those matched, and only that branch will be updated.

See also [Why does Jenkins allow specifying multiple git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72646757/why-does-jenkins-allow-specifying-multiple-git-branches).